# Automatic sizing of Div Plus Scrollbar as Needed

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

This code functions close to what I am after:

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative; background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow; margin:0px; top:0px; left:0px; width:300px; height:200px;">
    <span id="heading" style="background-color:palevioletred; display:block; text-align:center">
        List of Data
    </span>
    <div id="container" style="position:relative; overflow: auto;  background-color:aquamarine; height:160px;">
            <ul id="data">
                <li>Data Item 1</li>
                <li>Data Item 2. This data item requires more than 300 px of width and wraps as expected.</li>
                <li>Data Item 3</li>
                <li>Data Item 4</li>
                <li>Data Item 5</li>
                <li>Data Item 6</li>
                <li>Data Item 7</li>
                <li>Data Item 8</li>
                <li>Data Item 9</li>
                <li>Data Item 10. A vertical scrollbar has been added to the list div</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I have difficulties is the height of the "container" div. It seems to inherit the width of the "outer" div just fine, but it's height is not restricted by that of the "outer" div. If I remove the height from the "container" div, it uses up as much height as is needed for the data, causing it to fill less than the space available when there is less data, and overflow beyond the height specified by the "outer" div when there is more data. What I want is for the "container" div to consume exactly the balance of the space available in the "outer" div as per the "outer" div style settings (after accounting for the height required by the "heading" span), adding a vertical scrollbar to the "container" div when needed? Note I am looking for a strictly html/css solution.This is how the code looks:

[image]

If I remove the height style from the "container div", this is how it looks:

[image]

I want the appearance not to change. I want the height of the "container" div to be controlled by the "outer" div height setting.

Comment: Not clear sorry, if you can simplify explanation or maybe show a graphic example of the desired effect would be best.

Comment: Thanks, I added two images that I hope clarify what I am asking.

Comment: You mean to preserve that yellow footer below container?

Comment: No, actually I want the "container" div to fill the space provided as defined by the "outer" div. The yellow footer is a byproduct of the height for the "container" div not being set exactly correct to fill the "outer" div. What I am demonstrating with the images is that if I remove the height setting from the "container" div, I have the undesired effect of the "container" div extending beyond the boundary of the "outer" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest flexbox for the `#outer` parent div. With this setup, you control `#container`'s `height` from `#outer`'s `height` value.

```
#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
#outer {
  position: relative; 
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; 
  margin: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  width: 300px; 
  /* changes made */
  height: 195px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#heading {
  background-color:palevioletred; 
  display:block; 
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  position: relative; 
  overflow: auto;  
  background-color:aquamarine; 
  /* height:160px; */
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <span id="heading">
        List of Data
    </span>
    <div id="container">
            <ul id="data">
                <li>Data Item 1</li>
                <li>Data Item 2. This data item requires more than 300 px of width and wraps as expected.</li>
                <li>Data Item 3</li>
                <li>Data Item 4</li>
                <li>Data Item 5</li>
                <li>Data Item 6</li>
                <li>Data Item 7</li>
                <li>Data Item 8</li>
                <li>Data Item 9</li>
                <li>Data Item 10. A vertical scrollbar has been added to the list div</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```